# how to change the status text of http response in golang like 200 OK to 200 {Custom text}

Tags: http, go

I want to change the response text for the given status code in GO. how to do it.

Currently the status text for some popular status code is like this:
200 -> `OK`
404 -> `NOT FOUND`
201 -> `CREATED`

I want to change the text with my message like 
200 -> {MY CUSTOM MESSAGE}

Comment: The net/http package does not provide a way to set custom status text.

Comment: This smells like an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to change the response, you could use net package of golang and implement your own HTTP-like protocol instead of using net/http.

Answer (score 1):

The Reason-Phrase in the Status-Line is fixed and you should not change it. Really, Don't. Stick to the official format, e.g.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

But this is independent from the Body you send (where appropriate). Nothing prevents you from sending a body like this

```
http.Error(w, "Good boy! Well done!", http.StatusOK)
```

But again: changing the status line is a Bad Idea.